# Redirecting to page not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this function :

```
public function index(Request $request){
  $email = $request->email;
 $password = $request->password;

if (!$email || !$password) {return redirect()->back();}
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    $this->loggedUser = Auth::user();
    if($this->loggedUser){
          return redirect('http://localhost:3000/home');
    }

}
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrorMessage('Uneseni podaci nisu ispravni.');

}
```

What i want is to redirect user if he is logged in, but nothing happend. When i open i browser preview it just say

```
Redirecting to http://localhost:3000/home
```

But it not redirect me. Any suggestion?

When i enter manually it appears

Comment: try `redirect('/home')`

Comment: same problem.. it just say redirectin in preview but nothing is happening

Comment: the other redirects in this method work fine?

Comment: http://192.168.1.250:3000/  there is my problem...redirection is not working at all

Comment: Im using angularjs2 for this..if that means anything to you

Answer (score 0):

Change redirect address to this:

```
return redirect('home');
```

Comment: again nothing happen but in preview it say :
Redirecting to http://localhost:8000/home.   and thats it.... in my browser route is  http://localhost:3000.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to an absolute URL you can try this:

```
return redirect(url('http://localhost:8000/home'));
```

Or you can try this for relative URL:

```
return redirect('/home'));
```

> First one is bad because If your domain (http://localhost:8000) is
>   changed then all of your links are needed to be changed. So Second
>   approach is better.

Comment: I know but for me its not working... maybe because im using angular

Comment: If you are sending AJAX request, redirection won't work. You have to redirect from your front-end with Javascript or Angular routing

Comment: so i could return json response and then handle that in angular and set route?